# Sample from Gaussian Process across 2D

Tags: r, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

This seems like a straightforward questions; my apologies if it is already answered (I have looked).

**Problem**: I would like to sample from a Gaussian Process (GP) prior over X and Y coordinates (e.g. Lat, Lon). I would then like to fit data points on these two dimensions. I would like to use the analytical form as opposed to MCMC and compute it in R.

**Examples**: David Duvenaud's [Kernel Cookbook](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/) describes the multidimensional product kernel and illustrates a sample from the prior (below). The PDF of his thesis also illustrates data fitted to this kernel. 
[image: multi-dimensional models]

**Code**: For the 1-dimensional case; in R I am computing a basic squared exponential (aka RBF, Gaussian, etc...) kernel on the index `x.star` and pulling samples from multivariate normal with mean zero and sigma `sigma`. (code based on James Keirstead example)

```
require("MASS")
require("plyr")
require("reshape2")
require("ggplot2")
set.seed(12345)

#   a covariance matrix
calcSigma <- function(X1,X2,l=5,s=0.5) {
  Sigma <- matrix(rep(0, length(X1)*length(X2)), nrow=length(X1))
  for (i in 1:nrow(Sigma)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(Sigma)) {
      Sigma[i,j] <- exp(-s*(abs(X1[i]-X2[j])/l)^2)
    }
  }
  return(Sigma)
}

x.star <- seq(1,50,len=100)
sigma <- calcSigma(x.star,x.star)

# Generate a number of functions from the process
n.samples <- 10
values <- matrix(rep(0,length(x.star)*n.samples), ncol=n.samples)
for (i in 1:n.samples) {
  values[,i] <- mvrnorm(1, rep(0, length(x.star)), sigma)
}
values <- cbind(x=x.star,as.data.frame(values))
values <- melt(values,id="x")

ggplot(values,aes(x=x,y=value)) +
  geom_rect(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-2, ymax=2, 
            fill="grey90", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(group=variable)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(lim=c(-2.5,2.5), name="output, f(x)") +
  xlab("input, x")
```

[image: 1D Prior draws]

I am then using the below form to extract posterior samples with noise:
[image: GP Posterior with noise]

I would like to be able to samples across and X and Y coordinates from a product squared exponential kernel.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the question?  If you are able to do the 1d case, extension to 2d inputs should be straightforward

Comment: Exactly, it should be but I am a bit dense. I guess the question is, how to I sample for all pairs of points on both `x1` and `x2` input vectors so that a 2D surface can be plotted? Apologies that I can not articulate it much better than than.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an analytical solution to this. Turns out all of the action is in the kernel; not in the sampling from the multivariate normal. The key is to compute a pairwise distance grid across the two input dimensions. This takes it from an n x n problem to an n^2 x n^2 problem. See code below.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("plgp")

# kernel function
rbf_D <- function(X,l=1, eps = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps) ){
  D <- plgp::distance(X)
  Sigma <- exp(-D/l)^2 + diag(eps, nrow(X))
}
# number of samples
nx <- 30
x <- seq(0,2,length=nx)
# grid of pairwise values
X <- expand.grid(x, x)
# compute squared exponential kernel on pairwise values
Sigma <- rbf_D(X,l=2)

# sample from multivariate normal with mean zero, sigma = sigma
Y <- MASS::mvrnorm(1,rep(0,dim(Sigma)[1]), Sigma)

# plot results
pp <- data.frame(y=Y,x1=X[,1],x2=X[,2])
ggplot(pp,aes(x=x1,y=x2)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill=y), interpolate = TRUE) +
  geom_contour(aes(z=y), bins = 12, color = "gray30", 
               size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "viridis")
```

[image: bivariate input GP]

based on [code](http://bobby.gramacy.com/teaching/rsm/lect6.html#1) from Robert Gramacy.

Comment: wow, this looks so cool! are there ready made functions we can use for this, instead of using the long form functions?

Comment: Hello @Noob, not that I am aware of in R. There may be, but I have not worked in this area for some years.